# Use of common methods within other Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What is the proper way to use method `isValidEmail` within `compA.vue` and some other hypothetical `compB.vue`?

This approach doesn't work for me:

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Validators',
    methods: {
        isValidEmail(someEmail) {
            //Omitted
        },
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{isValidEmail('test1@gmail.com')}}</div>
</template>
<script>
import Validators from 'validators.vue'

export default {
    name: 'CompA',
    components: {
        'validators': Validators
    },  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are they parent/child or unrelated?

Comment: Unrelated. I am trying to find how to use a common 'repository' for javascripts methods wich I can use inside unrelated vue components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use mixins: you define in the mixin the function `isValidEmail` and then you import the mixin in the components you need.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html - Vue v2
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html - Vue v3

For example, instead creating a component `Validators.vue` as you did in your example, you can create a mixin named `Validators.js` as per below:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        isValidEmail(someEmail) {
            //Omitted
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can import the mixin in the components you need:

```js
<template>
    <div>{{isValidEmail('test1@gmail.com')}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import MixinValidator from 'Validators.js'

export default {
    name: 'CompA',
    mixins: [ MixinValidator ],
}
</script>
```

In this way, the component `CompA` will inherit all the functions, data and computed property defined in the mixin.